# TextBox tab order on validating

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# Windows Forms project that have 3 `TextBox`es (textbox1, textbox2 and textbox3).

Here is the code of textBox1 validating event:

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == "1")
        textBox2.Enabled = false;
    else
        textBox2.Enabled = true;
}
```

When textbox1 value is 1 and press "Tab" key
textbox2 disabled but the cursor still stay on textbox1
not focus to textbox3 ??

Then I change textbox1 value to 2 and press "Tab" key again
textbox2 enabled but the cursor focus to textbox3...??

Comment: It had already decided to move the focus to textbox2, that's what got the Validating event to fire.  But then it jerked the floor mat by disabling it.  Same story for the the other scenario, it couldn't decide to focus textbox2 since it was disabled, so opted for textbox3.

Answer (score 0):

In order to cursor still to the desired button, you must use the focus function
In the first case, you must call the following function(back Focus to textBox1)

```
 textBox1.Focus();
```

And for the second mode, you should call the following function(back Focus to textBox3)

```
 textBox3.Focus();
```

final Method:

```
  private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
         
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && textBox1.Text.Trim() == "1")
            {
                textBox1.Focus();
                textBox2.Enabled = false;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && textBox1.Text.Trim() == "2")
            {
              
                textBox2.Enabled = true;
                textBox3.Focus();

            }
        }
```